# al post le falta la cookie cuando le pongo el header

Tags: javascript, .net

tengo un inconveniente. Estoy trabajando con un proyecto en webform y tengo que comunicarme con un webmethod.
La autenticación se hace con cookies y la cookie se setea así

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
                app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    LoginPath = new PathString("/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ExpiradoURL").ToString()),
                    LogoutPath = new PathString("/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ExpiradoURL").ToString()),
                    CookieName = "CookieUniSession",
                    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    SlidingExpiration = true
                });
            }
```

El flujo de mi programa es que llegan a una página en .net donde valido algunas cosas de la persona y si existe creo una cookie con algunos claims y lo redirecciono a la aplicación de vue de esta forma

```
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
var userIdentity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

var authClaims = new List<Claim>();
var token = ObtenerToken(perfiles.First());
authClaims.Add(new Claim("TOKEN", ""));
authClaims.Add(new Claim("SIGN", ""));
userIdentity.AddClaims(authClaims);

var perfilesString = String.Join(";", perfiles.Select(x => x.tokenTipoUsuario + '-' + x.TokenSistema + "-" + x.tokengrupo));

authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, userIdentity);
var baseURLVue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("baseURLVue").ToString();
var redirectURL = baseURLVue + "selectorsistemas" + "?perfiles=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(perfilesString);
Response.Redirect(redirectURL, false);
```

Estoy intentado hacer un post desde vue (**el servidor del net está en un puerto y el servidor donde corre la app de vue en otro**) de esta forma

```js
fetch(baseUrl+'data/APIs/Usuarios.aspx/GetPerfilesToken', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache': 'no-cache'
      },
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify({salame:56})
    }).then((response) => response.json()) // Parse the response as JSON
    .then((data) => console.log(data)) // Do something with the data
    .catch((error) => console.error(error)); // Handle errors
```

El método al que intento llegar es este

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod( ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string GetPerfilesToken()
        {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                        { "result", "success"}, { "valor", "" } });
            
        }
```

Mi problema es que la cookie solo se envía si comento el header, pero si no lo pongo el content type es **text/plain;charset=UTF-8** y yo necesito que sea **application/json**
No entiendo por qué cuando agrego los headers pierdo la cookie.
la config de la cookie es httpOnly, el dominio es localhost y el path es / y expiración session.

Mi configuración en web.config para cors es

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:9000" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
</customHeaders>
```

EDITADO:

Según pude ver en intentos posteriores, a pesar de la configuración del web.config, el problema es el CORS. Cuando hago la llamada sin los headers, como no llega a llamar al webmethod, me devuelve un html y no hay ningún problema, pero en cuanto le pongo el header y llama correctamente al método salta el problema de CORS y no estoy viendo la cookie, porque el problema aparece en en prefliht.
Seguiré intentado

EDITADO 2:
Bueno, continuando con la investigación parece que el problema es que cuando se hace un request con el verbo **OPTIONS**, devuelve un 404 a menos que ponga esto en el web.config

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
     {
           HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
     }
}
```

Comment: Hola Leandro, proba poner `credentials: 'same-origin'`

Comment: Hola @Marcos ya probé, el comportamiento es el mismo

Comment: Bueno, no pude solucionar el problema de una mejor forma, pero por fin entendí todo lo que pasaba en esta otra pregunta
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it
En particular en la respuesta correcta y el edir del 13/09/2018